# Knockout get foreach to work

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

I´m having this object containing 3 notes

```
{
 notes:[
 {
   id:{type:"integer",value:"215356161"},
   body:"", 
   author_id:"980766",
   subject_id:"201674760",
   created_at:{date:"2014-03-24 16:50:14",timezone_type:2,timezone:"Z"},
   attachments:{
         type:"array",
         attachments:[{
             id:{type:"integer",value:"77791298"},
             url:"https://fdgsgds.highrisehq.com/files/777915446298",
             name:"nav-rubik-03.mp3",
             size:"13954"
       ]} //typo
   }
 },
 {
   id:{type:"integer",value:"215356129"},
   body:"Test",author_id:"980766",
   subject_id:"201674760",
   created_at:{date:"2014-03-24 16:50:08",timezone_type:2,timezone:"Z"}
 },
 {

 ...
 }]
}
```

i want to iterate over it

the second foreach doesnt work

```
<div data-bind="foreach: appModel.issue().highriseNotes()">
    <p data-bind="text:$data.created_at.date"></p>

    <p data-bind="text:$data.body"></p>
    <!-- UPDATE, The Solution was to check if there were attachments at all -->
    <!-- ko if:$data.attachments -->
   <div data-bind="foreach: $data.attachments.attachments)">
       <p data-bind="text:$data">   </p>                                                        
   </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

resulting in

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding 
"text: function (){return $data.attachments.attachments }"
Message: Cannot read property 'attachments' of undefined
```

how do i iterate over the "attachments" in "attachments"

Comment: There are several typos in your code, can you clean those up?

Comment: There is no 2nd foreach!

Comment: now there is, could pls mention anybody any of the several other typos ? i dont see one

Comment: here you go, updated the question

Comment: Your second item in the notes array doesn't have an `attachments` property

Comment: @RobertSlaney wow, i wrapped a <!-- ko if: $data.attachments --> arround an it worked, yeah that was it, feel free to make an answer

Comment: personally I think that you should fix your object model ( or JSON provider ) so that you will always have the attachments property with an empty inner attachments array.  An alternative is to filter the array

Comment: Answer generated with 2 additional suggestions.  An "if" binding feels a bit hackish to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the elements in the array is missing the attachment property, resulting in the binding failure you experienced.

A few solutions.

1 . Wrap the inner foreach in an if binding

```
<!-- ko if:$data.attachments -->
  <div data-bind="foreach..." />
<!-- /ko -->
```

2 . Ensure that you always have an attachments property in each notes element.  This may require a change to your JSON provider or serialiser, or just making sure your attachments property server side is either an empty array or list, depending on your technology stack.

```
{
  notes:[
  {
     ...
     attachments: {
       type:"array",
       attachments:[]           
     }
  }
}
```

3 .  Change the binding to default to an empty object.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ($data.attachments || {}).attachments)">
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following example I passed `notes` array into `ko.observableArray`.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Wb84f/1/